# Sed/awk/RegEX return the lines that ends with three colons

Tags: regex, linux, sed, awk

So I have several lines in a file that looks like this

```
useradmin:$NT$asdlfkjwaeroisglkwerlkj23424tlj:::  
useradmin:c2q3r4lsdfk23rlsdfkj3rjsdflk2k23:::
```

I am wondering if there's a script for sed and Regex to return these lines? I have tried the following and they didn't work.....

```
sed -n '/^\w+:{3}$/p' fileA.txt   
sed -n '/^\w:{3}$/p' fileA.txt
```

Thank you so much for helping out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use a brace quantifier with `sed` (if your version supports it), you either need to escape the curly braces or use `-r`. The same is true of the plus sign. However, `sed` doesn't support `\w`.

```
sed -nr '/^.+:{3}$/p' fileA.txt
```

or

```
sed -n '/^.\+:\{3\}$/p' fileA.txt
```

Comment: This answer is completely silly. Firstly `:{3}` is equivalent to `:::`, yet longer and more difficult to type. Secondly, `^.*` serves no purpose. It says "from the beginning of the string to here, there has to be at least one character".  Since the match is already anchored at the end, this can be expressed with a single `.`, as in:  `/.:::$/`. This means match three colons at the end of the line, preceded by a character. Of course there can be additional characters before that; that need not be mentioned. And this probably unnecessary, since a `:::` line probably means the file is malformed.

Comment: @Kaz: My answer addressed the OP's question as to why his use of quantifiers and escape didn't work. I used the same form he used and didn't address whether the regex might be "over-specified". As to whether `:{3}` is longer and more difficult to type than ':::', it is more flexible and easier to read. Silly answer? No. Matter of preference? Probably so.

Answer (score 2):

How about grep:

```
grep ":::$" fileA.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/.:::$/!d' fileA.txt
```